# Ограничения LIKE

Tags: mysql

Нужно найти в таблице `object_data` все объекты которые ставились игроками, по личному ID в столбце `Worldspace`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом список нужных игроков формируется по внутреннему запросу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий код в фантазиях автора:

```
SELECT * FROM `object_data` WHERE `Worldspace` LIKE 
(
SELECT
CONCAT('%',PlayerUID,'%')  
AS PlayerUID
FROM character_data
WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 31 DAY)
AND Alive = 1
)
```

Проблема состоит в том что LIKE не принимает более одного результата в переменной.
Как возможно обойти данное ограничение?

Написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM
( 
SELECT 
CONCAT('%',PlayerUID,'%')
AS PlayerUID
FROM character_data 
WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 31 DAY) 
AND Alive = 1 
) AS t2,
(
SELECT * FROM object_data
) AS t1
WHERE t1.Worldspace LIKE t2.PlayerUID
```

Работает корректно. Но при смене SELECT * FROM на DELETE FROM, таблица материться на вложенный запрос и показывает полное разнообразие ошибок при попытках заставить сию конструкцию работать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Подзапрос - в секцию FROM. И соответственно `WHERE t1.field LIKE t2.pattern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, должно работать как-то так:

```
select od.*
from object_data od
inner join character_data cd on od.Worldspace like CONCAT('%', cd.PlayerUID, '%')
where cd.LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY) and cd.Alive = 1
```